# How can I make rendered expressions by KaTex on a p5.js canvas show on downloaded images?

Tags: html, javascript, katex

I am trying to render LaTeX-Expressions with KaTeX on a p5.js canvas in order to export them together with the canvas as a png and use that elsewhere. The expressions render just fine, but when I download the image the rendered expressions are missing.

I suppose they are not part of the canvas-element, but what can I do to export them together with the canvas as one image?

Below is an image of the working part. The code produces the rendered expression, but when I download the canvas as an image I just get the grey backgroung.
[rendered KaTeX on a canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8n0A.png)

I originally used a library called p5.teach.js for the LaTeX rendering. I then found the posted sketch without the library, which leads to the same problem.

I tried to download into png and svg format, but that did not change anything. When I use the print-function of the browser the expressions are there, but I would like a clean download solution of just the canvas and the rendered expressions.

Comment: this is purely a javascript question so would be better on stackoverflow or a katex forum

Comment: I see. Thank you!